# DUP! Errors in ping 10.0.1.0

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, ping

When I ping my network at 10.0.1.0, I am seeing the following (DUP!) error. I know DUP! in pings  refers to duplicates, and is not good. Should I be concerned, and if so, can someone point me in a direction to solve this?

```
MacBook:~ pclark$ ping 10.0.1.0

PING 10.0.1.0 (10.0.1.0): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=1.171 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.556 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.1.6: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=3.649 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.1.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=219.607 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.1.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=221.927 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.165 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.445 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.456 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.1.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.549 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.0.1.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.559 ms (DUP!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you get the same response (the same [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) sequence number) from different ip addresses. I guess that your subnet is 255.255.255.0 (your network uses ip address range 10.0.1.x). If that's the case, no device should use the .0 or .255 address. The first address (.0) is known as the network address and that last address is the broadcast address. Most devices in the network should respond if you ping the broadcast address. Some (but not all) devices will also respond if you ping the network address. It appears that several devices (.1, .2, .3, .6 and .8) responded to your ping request.

Your solution: give the device that's on .0 an other ip address. How you should do that dependes on your device. I think there are three common scenario's:

- The .0 device is your router: log in to your router management software and change its address.
- The .0 device had a static ip address: change it on that device to something else
- The .0 device gets it from a DHCP server: change your DHCP settings to hand out ip addresses starting at .1 instead of at .0